# Отображение полей связанных моделей ADO .NET

Tags: mvc, ado.net

Выполняя тестовое задание для одной компании (условия которого было не использовать Entety и прочие ORM), столкнулся с проблемой: как наиболее оптимально и правильно выводить во `View` связанные модели.

Есть к примеру два класса:
`Authors`:

```
public partial class Author
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(50), Display(Name = "Firstname")]
    public string firstname { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(50), Display(Name = "Lastname")]
    public string lastname { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date of birth"), DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime dateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

И `Book`, который имеет массив айдишников на авторов `idAuthors`

```
public class Book
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(100), Display(Name = "Name book")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(4000), Display(Name = "Description"), DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string description { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Pages")]
    public short countPages { get; set; }

    [Required, Display(Name = "Publication"), DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime dateOfPublication { get; set; }

    [Required, Display(Name = "Authors")]
    public int[] idAuthors { get; set; }

    [Required, Display(Name = "Count")]
    public int count { get; set; }
}
```

Я делал это так. В контроллере во `ViewBag` передавал коллекцию всех авторов

```
public ActionResult Index(int? page)
{
    IEnumerable<Book> books = repository.Books.GetAll();
    if (booksInfo == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    ViewBag.AllAuthors = repository.Authors.GetAll();

    int pageSize = 5;
    int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

    return View(books.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
}
```

И во `View` при выводе в цикле их проверял

```
@foreach (var author in (List<TaskLibrary.Models.Author>)ViewBag.AllAuthors)
{
    if (item.idAuthors.Contains(author.id))
    {
        <p>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => author.NameFull)
        </p>
    }
}
```

Но не думаю, что это правильно...